# Old system breaks Webpage when browsing

Tags: linux, browser, operating-system

So I have an old system(Lenovo-g500s). I clean installed Linux Mint XFCE 21.1. I am currently using usb tethering and external wifi for internet.

The problem that i am facing is that only in this particular system [this](https://ttelobby.indianrail.gov.in/) website throws errors related to post and get method.

I have been using facebook and other sites with not problem at all.
I have tried the Cinnamon version too along with the Ubuntu 23.04 but faced the same issue.

I am a beginner and so don't know what codes or outputs to paste so please ask.

Will System info be helpfull:

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.3.0 Desktop: Xfce 4.16.0
    tk: Gtk 3.24.23 wm: xfwm dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 21.1 Vera base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20245 v: Lenovo G500s serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10
    v: Lenovo G500s serial: <filter>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: INVALID v: 31900004WIN8 STD SGL serial: <filter> UEFI: LENOVO
    v: 7BCN21WW(V1.05) date: 04/18/2013
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 12.2 Wh (57.5%) condition: 21.2/37.5 Wh (56.4%) volts: 15.5 min: 14.9
    model: LENOVO PABAS0241231 serial: <filter> status: N/A
CPU:
  Info: dual core model: Intel Core i3-3120M bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Ivy Bridge rev: 9 cache:
    L1: 128 KiB L2: 512 KiB L3: 3 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2494 min/max: 1200/2500 cores: 1: 2494 2: 2494 3: 2494 4: 2494
    bogomips: 19953
  Flags: avx ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel ports:
    active: LVDS-1 empty: DP-1,HDMI-A-1,VGA-1 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:0166
  Device-2: NVIDIA GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] vendor: Lenovo
    driver: nouveau v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 8 bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:1140
  Device-3: Acer Lenovo Integrated Webcam type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 3-4:2
    chip-ID: 5986:0295
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 compositor: xfwm v: 4.16.1 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 display-ID: :0.0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1366x768 s-dpi: 96
  Monitor-1: LVDS-1 model: Samsung res: 1366x768 dpi: 101 diag: 395mm (15.5")
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2) v: 4.2 Mesa 22.0.5 compat-v: 3.1
    direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Definition Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:1e20
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-56-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet vendor: Lenovo driver: alx v: kernel pcie:
    speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: 2000 bus-ID: 02:00.0 chip-ID: 1969:10a0
  IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Lenovo driver: ath9k
    v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 168c:0032
  IF: wlp3s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-3: Realtek RTL8188FTV 802.11b/g/n 1T1R 2.4G WLAN Adapter type: USB driver: r8188eu
    bus-ID: 1-1.2:6 chip-ID: 0bda:f179
  IF: wlx00e04c818802 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: usb0 state: unknown speed: -1 duplex: half mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 1-1.3:3
    chip-ID: 0cf3:3004
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 2.1 lmp-v: 4.0 sub-v: 1
  Device-2: Xiaomi Mi/Redmi series (RNDIS) type: USB driver: rndis_host v: kernel bus-ID: 3-1:4
    chip-ID: 2717:ff80
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 12.12 GiB (2.6%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: HGST (Hitachi) model: HTS545050A7E680 size: 465.76 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s
    serial: <filter>
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 456.89 GiB used: 12.11 GiB (2.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 5.2 MiB (1.0%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 132 MiB (6.4%) priority: -2 file: /swapfile
USB:
  Hub-1: 1-0:1 info: Full speed or root hub ports: 2 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002
  Hub-2: 1-1:2 info: Intel Integrated Rate Matching Hub ports: 6 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s
    chip-ID: 8087:0024
  Device-1: 1-1.2:6 info: Realtek RTL8188FTV 802.11b/g/n 1T1R 2.4G WLAN Adapter type: Network
    driver: r8188eu rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 0bda:f179
  Device-2: 1-1.3:3 info: Qualcomm Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 type: Bluetooth driver: btusb
    rev: 1.1 speed: 12 Mb/s chip-ID: 0cf3:3004
  Device-3: 1-1.4:4 info: Realtek RTS5129 Card Reader Controller type: <vendor specific>
    driver: rtsx_usb,rtsx_usb_ms,rtsx_usb_sdmmc rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 0bda:0129
  Hub-3: 2-0:1 info: Full speed or root hub ports: 2 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002
  Hub-4: 2-1:2 info: Intel Integrated Rate Matching Hub ports: 6 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s
    chip-ID: 8087:0024
  Hub-5: 3-0:1 info: Hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 4 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s
    chip-ID: 1d6b:0002
  Device-1: 3-1:4 info: Xiaomi Mi/Redmi series (RNDIS) type: Bluetooth,CDC-Data
    driver: rndis_host rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 2717:ff80
  Device-2: 3-4:2 info: Acer Lenovo Integrated Webcam type: Video driver: uvcvideo rev: 2.0
    speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 5986:0295
  Hub-6: 4-0:1 info: Super-speed hub ports: 4 rev: 3.0 speed: 5 Gb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0003
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 69.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: apt: 2050
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
    1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg] https: //brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https: //dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
    1: deb https: //mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/linuxmint-mirror/packages vera main upstream import backport
    2: deb http: //repos.del.extreme-ix.org/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse
    3: deb http: //repos.del.extreme-ix.org/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
    4: deb http: //repos.del.extreme-ix.org/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    5: deb http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
Info:
  Processes: 252 Uptime: 1h 21m Memory: 3.7 GiB used: 2.3 GiB (62.2%) Init: systemd v: 249
  runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.3.0 alt: 11 Client: Unknown python3.10 client inxi: 3.3.13
```